# Schema Lock Test in Model Builder for ArcGIS 10.0 Desktop

Tags: arcgis-10.0, modelbuilder, feature-class

I have made a model (Model Builder) that exports a Polygon Layer from a Parcel Fabric and Exports it as a set of Features Classes into a set of Feature Datasets. However, there are often other people working within the datasets. I would like to be able to check the dataset for a schema lock before trying to save the data, and then if possible keep checking until the schema lock is removed and the model can complete the process. Is this possible within model builder, and how?

Answer (score 1):

You can call arcpy in Model Builder for check lock schema.
Remove lock on feature class:

[Remove lock on feature class](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/31034/remove-lock-on-feature-class)

[Interaction ArcPy with Model Builder](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/21579/arcgis-iterate-files-tool-in-model-builder)