# How to copy or export list filter from one model to another?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, modelbuilder

I have a model tool with a variable parameter that is filtered by a string list (county names) I manually created this list filter when I created the model tool. I am now creating a new model tool and would like to use the same list of county names is there anyway to import the list filter from my other model so I do not have to manually create the list again. I am an amateur at best with python so if it is possible to keep the solution within the realm of ModelBuilder that would be best but if python is neccessary bear with me.

This is the value list I would like to reuse
[image]

Comment: With that many values, it might be easier to list the filter of strings you **don't** want to include.

Comment: Iterate files in Model Builder see http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/21579/arcgis-iterate-files-tool-in-model-builder

Comment: I don't think there is anyway of exporting and importing your value list. Think about it when you created the original list you had to type them in by hand. I think "evil genius"'s solution is as good as it gets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to agree with Paul's comment, I think you may want to look at alternatives in the future.

That being said, you could copy your original model and remove everything but that variable/parameter in the new copy and use that as your starting point. Even if you have to recreate or copy in other elements from another model it will still be quicker than recreating that filter list...

Comment: Thanks guys the copy solution works for the quick fix I need. I agree with you both that this could be executed better/cleaner.